# Which interactions happen with terraform state and when?

Tags: terraform

I suppose is like this:

- `terraform init` -> No interactions with the state file
- `terraform plan` -> *Read* the state file
- `terraform apply` -> *Read* & *Write* the state file

Is this supposition correct?

Also, when the apply write in the state? Before or after the commands over the infra are finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that is a good high level overview of the different state interactions for the main commands. If you are using remote state, then init does interact with it to make sure it can access it. Since Terraform can fail with a partially ran script, you can determine that Terraform writes to state as each resource is updated/created. That way state reflects what was currently successful. If you kill a Terraform run before the resource gets finished, the state isn't updated.

Comment: `terraform init` also reads the latest state snapshot in order to check if there are any resource instances that need providers that aren't currently accounted for in the configuration, so that a subsequent `terraform apply` would be able to destroy those objects.